# How to generate a valid ES256 signature in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cryptography, jwt, mapkit

I'm working to integrate Map Web Snapshot (part of the Apple MapKit SDK for web) where I need to append a signature of the URL to the query parameters. The example code in the documentation demonstrates how to achieve this using the `jwa` package from NPM.

```js
// Required modules.
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");
const { sign } = require("jwa")("ES256");

/* Read your private key from the file system. (Never add your private key
 * in code or in source control. Always keep it secure.)
 */ 
const privateKey = readFileSync("[file_system_path]");
// Replace the team ID and key ID values with your actual values.
const teamId = "[team ID]";
const keyId = "[key ID]";

// Creates the signature string and returns the full Snapshot request URL including the signature.
function sign(params) {
    const snapshotPath = `/api/v1/snapshot?${params}`;
    const completePath = `${snapshotPath}&teamId=${teamId}&keyId=${keyId}`;
    const signature = sign(completePath, privateKey);
    // In this example, the jwa module returns the signature as a Base64 URL-encoded string.

    // Append the signature to the end of the request URL, and return.
    return `${completePath}&signature=${signature}`;
}

// Call the sign function with a simple map request.
sign("center=apple+park") 

// The return value expected is: "/api/v1/snapshot?center=apple+park&teamId=[team ID]&keyId=[key ID]&signature=[base64_url_encoded_signature]"
```

I want to achieve the same thing, but instead in Ruby.

```rb
key_id = ENV['MAPKIT_KEY_ID']
team_id = ENV['MAPKIT_TEAM_ID']
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(ENV['MAPKIT_PRIVATE_KEY'])

def sign(params)
  snapshot_path = "/api/v1/snapshot?#{params}"
  complete_path = "#{snapshot_path}&teamId=#{team_id}&keyId=#{key_id}"
  signature = JWT::Signature.sign('ES256', complete_path, private_key)
  "#{complete_path}&signature=#{signature}"
end
```

However, the output I get from the call to `JWT::Signature.sign` isn't what I expect. In the JavaScript example I always get back an 86 character string - something like `T9ENYiGPQHoRQXkNMLlidCL0lrwTR1mra9cIurhAiprdZpM7a-74mNh3DOYXi--FvPOxdUW0Omr-6jo3FWyLFQ`. In the Ruby example I get something totally different - `"\x95\xA7\x8A4L\x82>\f_\u0002\xBC_1~;\xAE\xBF\xE5\xC5\u0019W\x86\xDEwG\u0004i\x93CYX\xD2\u0018\x84\\\xD9\xFDf\x877\xF7|rnf\u007FV\xF2<\xA2\u0010\u0003f\xE3)\x8A6n,\f\u0011\xB7#\xDE"`.

Am I on the right path for using ES256 to sign strings in Ruby, or what do I need to do in order to get the expected result in Ruby?

Comment: That looks like raw binary. I think you need to base64 encode it. Check out `encode_signature` in this file: https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/blob/master/lib/jwt/encode.rb

Comment: Thank you - I thought it may have been some encoding issue but I couldn't work out what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Casper and @endemic were correct in that it's an encoding issue.

You can use `Base64.urlsafe_encode64` or use `JWT::Base64.url_encode` if you want to stick to the gem.

```rb
signature = JWT::Signature.sign('ES256', complete_path, private_key)
JWT::Base64.url_encode(signature)
```

Answer (score 1):

"base64url" your `signature` variable, like so:

```rb
signature = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(JWT::Signature.sign('ES256', complete_path, private_key))
```